Interior elliptic estimates in Nicolaescu's book
I am trying to understand the proof of interior elliptic estimates in Nicolaescu's book, but there is an important step, which I do not get, and I ask for help.
The reference is https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf, Theorem 10.3.1 on p. 491, step 2 of the proof, p. 493-494 (pages of the pdf file).
We have an elliptic operator $$L=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}A_\alpha(x)\partial^\alpha$$
on a trivial bundle on $\mathbb R^N$ and we want to prove an estimate $$\|u\|_{m,p}\leq C(\|Lu\|_p+\|u\|_p).$$
We established it for constant coefficients, and now we want to deduce for non-constant ones. The support of $u$ is in a ball $B_R$, which is covered by some set of small balls $B_r(x_\nu)$. We pick a partition of unity $\eta_\nu$ subordinate to the covering. They satisfy some properties, but I do not think that it is relevant.
We set $$u_\nu:=\eta_\nu u,~~~~~v_\nu:=Lu_\nu,~~~~L_\nu:=\sum_{|\alpha|=m}A_\alpha(x_\nu)\partial^\alpha,~~~~\varepsilon_{\alpha,\nu}(x):=A_\alpha(x_\nu)-A_\alpha(x).$$
Using the already proven case of constant coefficients, we write
$$\|u_\nu\|_{m,p}\leq C(\|L_\nu u_\nu\|_p+\|u_\nu\|_p).$$
Now we substitute there $$L_\nu u_\nu=(L_\nu-L)u_\nu+v_\nu$$
and get
$$\|u_\nu\|_{m,p}\leq C(\sum_{|\alpha|=m}\|\varepsilon_{\alpha,\nu}(x)\partial^\alpha u_\nu\|_p+\|u_\nu\|_{m-1,p}+\|v_\nu\|_p+\|u_\nu\|_p).$$
Here comes the thing that I do not understand. Nicolaescu writes "Since $\varepsilon_{\alpha,\nu}(x)\leq Cr$ ... we deduce
$$\|u_\nu\|_{m,p}\leq C(r\|u_\nu\|_p+\|v_\nu\|_p+\|u_\nu\|_p)."$$
Why is this? It seems that suddenly all derivatives of $u_\nu$ got somehow bounded via $\|u_\nu\|_p$, but how could the derivatives get bounded by this? (As for me, that's the main mystery of this result, and I still struggle to understand it.) Also on the line just before, at some point it is written just $u$ instead of $u_\nu$, but then it turns to $u_\nu$ again, so I assume that this was a simple typo. (Or could it be a feature rather than a bug?)
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Looks like the Lipschitz continuity of $x \mapsto A_\alpha$ is used.

@daw, I guess, this is used in $\varepsilon_{\alpha,\nu}(x)\leq Cr$? This I understand. I don't understand, where all derivatives of $u_\nu$ disappear.

Some indices are missing: the first inequality should have $r |u|{m,p}+ |v|{m,p}+|u|{m-1,p}$ on the rhs, the second $|v|{m,p}+|u|_{m-1,p}$
